# Qt: find widget "Could not parse stylesheet of object"?

Tags: qt, qstylesheet

I am getting warnings: "Could not parse stylesheet of object "; actually, several warnings, all with the same address

I inherited a project with a gazillion widgets and with the stylesheets moved to .cpp files -- how can I find what QObject (QWidget?) has the problem? On what function can I set a breakpoint, or how in MSVC 2015 can I debug the object as a QObject or QWidget (and thus get its name)?

Comment: You could use [qInstallMessageHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler) to install your own error message handler and put a breakpoint in that.